# Locate pixel by color return point

Tags: c#, image, gdi+, lockbits

I need to locate the points/cordinates (x,y) of the first pixel it finds with the specified color. 
I have used the GetPixel() method, but it's a bit too slow and were looking into LockBits. How ever I can't figure out if this actually could solve my problem. Can I return the points for the found pixel using LockBits?

Here is my current code:

```
public Point FindPixel(Image Screen, Color ColorToFind)
{
    Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(Screen);
    BitmapData bmpData = bit.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bit.Width, bit.Height),
                                    ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                                    PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
    unsafe
    {
        byte* ptrSrc = (byte*)bmpData.Scan0;
        for (int y = 0; y < bmpData.Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < bmpData.Width; x++)
            {
                Color c = bit.GetPixel(x, y);
                if (c == ColorToFind)
                    return new Point(x, y);
            }
        }
    }
    bit.UnlockBits(bmpData);
    return new Point(0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things wrong with your code:

1. You are using PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb - you should use pixel format of the image, if they won't match, all pixels will be copied under the hood anyways.
2. You are still using `GetPixel`, so all this hassle will not give you any advantage.

To use `LockBits` efficiently, you basically want to lock your image and then use unsafe pointers to get values of pixels. Code to do this will vary a bit for different pixel formats, assuming you really will have 32bpp format with blue being on LSB, your code could look like this:

```
for (int y = 0; y < bmpData.Height; ++y)
{ 
    byte* ptrSrc = (byte*)(bmpData.Scan0 + y * bmpData.Stride);
    int* pixelPtr = (int*)ptrSrc;

    for (int x = 0; x < bmpData.Width; ++x)
    {
        Color col = Color.FromArgb(*pixelPtr);

        if (col == ColorToFind) return new Point(x, y);

        ++pixelPtr; //Increate ptr by 4 bytes, because it is int
    }
}
```

Few remarks:

- For each line new ptrSrc is computed using Scan0 + stride value. This is because just increasing the pointer might fail, if `Stride != bpp * width`, which may be the case.
- I assumed that blue pixel is represented as LSB, and alpha as MSB, which I think was not the case, because those GDI pixel formats were.. strange ;), just make sure you check it, if it's the other way, inverse bytes before using `FromArgb()` method.
- If your pixel format is 24bpp, it's a bit more tricky, because you can't use int pointer and increase it by 1 (4 bytes), for obvious reasons.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked really well and it's blazing fast now! :)
I were still using the GetPixel(), just to illustrate what I wanted to do with LockBits.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't stop using GetPixel() so you are not ahead.  Write it like this instead:

```
    int IntToFind = ColorToFind.ToArgb();
    int height = bmpData.Height;    // These properties are slow so read them only once
    int width = bmpData.Width;
    unsafe
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            int* pline = (int*)bmpData.Scan0 + y * bmpData.Stride/4;
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                if (pline[x] == IntToFind)
                    return new Point(x, bit.Height - y - 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

The odd looking Point constructor is necessary because lines are stored upside-down in a bitmap.  And don't return new Point(0, 0) on failure, that's a valid pixel.

Comment: I've never though of using `Color.ToArgb()` for this purpose. That's awesome!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can't get the pointer to return the right values though. Maybe my image are in the wrong format or something. Well thanks anyway :)

Comment: Hard to guess, watch out for the alpha value.